# Using git for game development with unity for multiple platforms

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, version-control

I'm starting to work on a Unity game and I want to use git for version control. It's a VR game, it will have versions for all major desktop VR platforms (Oculus, Vive, WMR), where the main difference will be the SDK, but also for the upcoming Oculus Quest. This one is a standalone headset so I will have to significantly optimize different parts of the game (code, models, shaders, textures). Still, most of the assets/code will be shared with the desktop VR versions.

Ideally I'd like to keep all these versions in the same repository, but I don't know how to solve this. Initially I wanted to use multiple branches and merge into them whenever I make a "universal" change, but after reading a little bit it seems that it's strongly discouraged. I've seen some people suggest using `#ifdef` but this works only in code and can get pretty messy. Is there any good solution to this problem?

Comment: Platform directives (such as `#ifdef`) and loading from AssetBundles that are made to be platform-specific would be my guess.

Comment: What do you mean by platform-specific AssetBundles? Also I would like to avoid using `#ifdef` if possible since it can cause some spaghetti code.

Comment: If you want to make a single asset that compiles differently between target platform, then use platform directives. If you want to make different versions of the same asset where each one is optimized for a specific platform, make an [AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) for each target platform, and put all of the asset versions for that platform in that AssetBundle. You will need script to load the appropriate assetbundle & assets from it at runtime. Or you can have completely separate project dirs in the same git repository, each dir a target platform.

Comment: That's a really great solution, but I think there is one problem. Some VR sdks have to be completely excluded form the project when building it (oculus store won't accept anything with steamvr references). Asset Bundles seem to be a good solution, but then I can't really reference any of those scripts/prefabs from the bundle when creating a level for example, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Also, there's nothing really spaghetti about platform directives if you use them to instantiate the appropriate concrete class for an interface that is common to all platforms.

Comment: Ther e is nothing wrong with using it in an interface class, but when I start writing platform specific code in let's say the AI engine I think it could get pretty messy.